# find the date difference to get number of years

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column which stores the student academic year (datatype :INT) as

summer 2010 = 201100

fall 2010 = 201110

Spring 2010 = 201120

if the current academic year is spring 2016 i.e 201720

how do i find the difference between the dates in years?

Comment: wouldn't spring 2016 be 201720 if spring 2010 is 201120? Also how are you supposed to figure out the months if the months are not part of the data?

Comment: What is the difference in months between `Summer 2010` and `Fall 2010`?

Comment: it should have been 201720, i have made an updated and i would just require years.

Comment: your dates make no sense to me. The first 4 digits are the year, what about '00', '10', '20'? They're obviously not month numbers.

Comment: Academic Year is defined by code as the year that the academic year ends.
Academic Year starts in Summer and Ends in Spring.

Comment: That doesn't really help. I can't work out your data structure so you're going to have to split the string (left 4, right 2) and convert this into a date using cast (calculated year, calculated month, 1) as date. You'll then want to do DATEDIFF(mm,date1,date2) to get the difference between these dates in months

Answer (score 0):

Translate your integer values to Datetime values (eg.  201120 becomes `2010-04-01` etc), and then use DateDiff().

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just use `LEFT` since you only need the years.

```
DECLARE @academic_year INT = 201100
DECLARE @current_academic_year INT = 201720

SELECT CAST(LEFT(@current_academic_year, 4) AS INT) - CAST(LEFT(@academic_year, 4) AS INT)
```

Comment: and it actually worked... i had tried the same way but received some error, but your query helped me to solve the prob. Thanks